# Select subset of records from very large SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

There are two tables, namely `LongTable` and `ShortTable`. For example, `LongTable` looks like:

```
personA | personB
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 4
2 | 5
3 | 4
3 | 5
3 | 6
4 | 5
4 | 6
```

and `ShortTable` has the following content:

```
PersonA
1
2
```

I wonder how to select records from a `LongTable` (please note that this table is really long, i.e. about 2.000.000 rows) based on records in the `ShortTable`. So, the result for this particular case should be:

```
personA | personB
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 4
2 | 5
```

I started with the following query (but with failure: "Can't reopen table: 'ShortTable'"):

```
SELECT * FROM LongTable
  WHERE
    personA IN (SELECT * FROM ShortTable)
    AND
    personB IN (SELECT * FROM ShortTable)
```

Code to reproduce temporary tables is given below.

Thanks in advance for any pointer.

```
CREATE TABLE LongTable (
  personA INT,
  personB INT
);

INSERT INTO LongTable VALUES
(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),
(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),
(3,6),(4,5),(4,6);

CREATE TABLE ShortTable (
  personA INT
);

INSERT INTO ShortTable VALUES
(1),(2);
```

Comment: why 1 and 2? and person b is 2,3,4,5?

Comment: @JohnWoo because `longtable.PersonA` = 1, 2 which is equal to `shorttable.PersonA`

Comment: oh it came from another table..grr did not see it.

Comment: @Andrej . . . Your query and your description of the results do not match.  Do you want personB to also be in the short table?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Thanks, but each desired row from LongTable is selected 4 times.

Comment: @Andrej Try to add `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT l.personA, l.personB
 FROM longTable l 
 INNER JOIN ShortTable s ON l.personA  = s.personA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
SELECT * FROM LongTable
WHERE personA IN (SELECT * FROM ShortTable)
```

Note that the running time usually depends on tables structure(e.g. indexes), rather than on query

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this in MySQL is to create an index on longTable.personA.  Then do the following query:

```
select l.personA, l.personB
from longTable l
where exists (select 1 from shortTable s where s.PersonA = l.PersonA limit 1)
```